# Ramda: Confused about pipe

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, function-composition

I'm learning functional programming in JS and I'm doing it with Ramda.

I'm trying to make a function that takes parameters and returns a list. Here is the code:

```
const list = R.unapply(R.identity);

list(1, 2, 3); // => [1, 2, 3]
```

Now I tried doing this using `pipe`:

```
const otherList = R.pipe(R.identity, R.unapply);

otherList(1,2,3);
// => function(){return t(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0))}
```

Which returns a weird function.

This:

```
const otherList = R.pipe(R.identity, R.unapply);

otherList(R.identity)(1,2,3); // => [1, 2, 3]
```

works for some reason.

I know this might be a newbie question, but how would you construct f(g(x)) with `pipe`, if f is `unapply` and g is `identity`?

Comment: Note that the spelling is 'Ramda', not 'Rambda'. I've edited for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the `R.unapply` [docs](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#unapply). It's a function that gets a function and returns a function, which can take multiple parameters, collect it to a single array, and pass it as the parameter for the wrapped function.

So in the 1st case, it converts `R.identity` to a function that can receive multiple parameters and return an array.

In the 2nd case, `R.unapply` gets the result of `R.identity` - a single value, and not a function. If you pass `R.identity` as a parameter to the pipe, `R.unapply` gets a function and return a function, which is similar to the 1st case.

To make `R.unapply` work with `R.pipe`, you need to pass `R.pipe` to `R.unapply`:

```js
const fn = R.unapply(R.pipe(
  R.identity
))

const result = fn(1, 2, 3)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Isn't `unapply(pipe(identity)))` the same as `unapply(identity)`?

Comment: @customcommander Yes, because the former is `unapply(x => identity(x)))`, which can be eta reduced to `unapply(identity))`

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though you really are thinking of `pipe` incorrectly.

When you use `unapply(identity)`, you are passing the *function* `identity` to `unapply`.

But when you try `pipe(identity, unapply)`, you get back a function that passes the *results* of calling `identity` to `unapply`.

That this works is mostly a coincidence: `pipe(identity, unapply)(identity)`.  Think of it as `(...args) => unapply(identity(identity))(...args)`.  Since `identity(identity)` is just `identity`, this turns into `(...args) => unapply(identity)(...args)`, which can be simplified to `unapply(identity)`.  This only means something important because of the nature of `identity`.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `unapply` to transform a function that would normally take its arguments as an array into a function that can take any number of positional arguments:

```
sum([1, 2, 3]); //=> 6
unapply(sum)(1, 2, 3) //=> 6
```

This allows you to, among many other things, map over any number of positional arguments:

```
unapply(map(inc))(1, 2) //=> [2, 3]
unapply(map(inc))(1, 2, 3) //=> [2, 3, 4]
unapply(map(inc))(1, 2, 3, 4) //=> [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`identity` will always return its first argument. So `unapply(identity)(1,2)` is the same as `identity([1,2])`.

If your end goal was to create a function that returns a list of its arguments, I don't think you needed `pipe` in the first place. `unapply(identity)` was already doing that.

However, if what you need to do is to make sure that your pipe gets its parameters as a list, then you simply need to wrap `pipe` with `unapply`:

```
const sumplusplus = unapply(pipe(sum, inc, inc));
sumplusplus(1, 2, 3); //=> 8
```